# PyQt cross platform installer builder

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, installation, pyqt

This is my first PyQt project. I am at the stage of making the setup/installer builder for various platforms. How do you build the installer? Like a wizard that takes the user through steps like accept license, select other options etc and finally copy your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it mentions halfway down this page:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities

> Installers are sometimes needed to wrap up the output of freeze tools
> into packages:
>
> - Inno Setup (Windows)
> - NSIS (Windows)
> - MacPython BundleBuilder (Mac OS X)

I've been involved with NSIS for installers at work, and they are pretty straight forward and easy to work with.  That is mostly for Windows deployment.

The other deployment tool I've used for Mac is [DMG Creator](http://dmgcreator.sourceforge.net/en/).  But that was mostly for a C++ project not python.  Mac and Linux almost always have a version of Python on it, but you may still want to have your build of Python available.

Hope that helps.

Comment: From above I have come to realize there is a difference between freeze tools and install builders. Pyinstaller, py2exe are freeze tools.Just tested Inno Setup and it looks great too. I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

What about a PyQt installer? With PyQt you have access to a QWizard component with which you can implement your functionality :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()               
        self.wizard = QtWidgets.QWizard()

        self.page1 = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("A label example")
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.page1.setLayout(self.vlayout)
        self.wizard.addPage(self.page1)

        self.page2 = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
        self.wizard.addPage(self.page2)

        self.wizard.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp()
```

that produces this output

[image]